# Magento 2: How to use 2 minicarts with same knockout template?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, mini-cart, knockout

In my site are use 2 minicarts (in header and sidebar) with same knockout template:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

I want to adjust small fixes, for sidebar minicart (only remove one button), and I don't want to create another one template.

How I can to check in knockout that it's exactly sidebar?

Something like that:

```
<button data-bind="visible: isSidebar()" />
```

It is possible? May I get root element in knockout template? If yes - I could to check sidebar html class.

Comment: You want to hide a button in sidebar , like want to hide "view cart " button ? if yes then you can do this job using css only , not need to touch any code

Comment: Yes, of course. But I would like to do this using knockout. It is possible?